# use Animate.css in ReactJS with react-animated-css

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, animate.css, react-animated

I am trying to implement `Animate.css` in React and throughout my researches I found the package `react-animated-css` which seems to be quiet straightforward, however I couldn't make it work.

In the documentation (if it's possible to call that a documentation) it's been said that the user should include the `Animate.css` in the HTML page, I didn't do that, since I am working with React and there is no HTML page, but I installed animate.css through npm.

Here follows a sample of my code:

```
import {Animated} from 'react-animated-css'

class ComponentTest extends Component {

  render () {

   return (
    <div>
      <Animated 
         animationIn="fadeInDown" 
         animationOut="zoomOut" 
         animationInDuration={1000} 
         animationOutDuration={1000} 
         isVisible={true}
      >
          <h1 style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>TESTE 1</h1>
      </Animated>
    </div>
   )
 }
}
```

I've also tried to set `isVisible` dynamically using a state, but without any success:

```
import {Animated} from 'react-animated-css'

class ComponentTest extends Component {

  state = {animacao: false}

  toggleAnimation = () => {

     let animacao = !this.state.animacao
     this.setState({animacao})
  }

  render () {

   return (
    <div>
      <Animated 
         animationIn="fadeInDown" 
         animationOut="zoomOut" 
         animationInDuration={1000} 
         animationOutDuration={1000} 
         isVisible={this.state.animacao}
      >
          <h1 style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>TESTE 1</h1>
      </Animated>
      <button onClick={this.toggleAnimation} >Animação</button>
    </div>
   )
 }
}
```

When I inspect my component I see that the classes are being applied in both cases:

[image]

Here is the page of the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animated-css

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

P.S. Using this package is not a must, I am completelly open to suggestions.

Comment: You need to include the animate.css file.  Running npm install doesn't do that for you.  You can add it to your `index.html` (there is one in React apps in the public folder); import into another css file that's included somewhere in your app using a css `@import`; or if your app is based on create-react-app, you can import it directly into a component file.

Comment: You have to include:

`<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head>`

in `./public/index.html` file.

Comment: You're both correct. It works great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `create-react-app` just import animate css like this `import 'animate.css'` in your `App.js` file. I hope it'll work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know you might have got the answer till now but it's `<Animate></Animate>` instead of `<Animated></Animated>` in your ComponentTest. It might have been 'Animated' in previous versions which I am not aware of. However, you can check it here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/animate.css-react